# Воникает ошибка WindowManager$BadTokenException при показе диалога

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

Возникает ошибка:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@19fb3f3e is not valid; is your activity running?
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:562)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:282)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:3422)
at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:3371)
at com.brokeyourapp.app123.StepGallery6$1.handleMessage(StepGallery6.java:481)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Я так понимаю возникает она при попытке создать диалог, когда activity не существует. И подозреваю что причина именно в том как я вызываю этот диалог.

В методе `onCreate` имеется Handler, который в определенном случае показывает диалог, вот так `showDialog(IDD_CONGRADS);`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stepgallery6);

        h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {

            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                // обновляем Кнопки
                switch (msg.what) {
                case 40:
                        if (Arrays.equals(compArray, compButtonArray)) {
                            //
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { showDialog(IDD_CONGRADS); } });
                        }
                        else {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { showDialog(IDD_NOCONGRADS); } });
                        }

                        break;
                    case 60:
                        GoAct(1);
                        break;

{

}
```

Влияние на Handler происходит вот так:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {

                try {
                 TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
                h.sendEmptyMessage(i);
        }}
    });
    t.start();

}
```

А функция по вызову выглядит вот так:

```
// Вызывает диалог по окончанию
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case IDD_CONGRADS:
                //AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(StepGallery6.this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.congrats1)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.next,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        GoAct(2);
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNeutralButton(R.string.back_to_menu,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        GoAct(1);
                                    }
                                });
                return builder.create();
            case IDD_NOCONGRADS:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(StepGallery6.this);
                builder2.setMessage(R.string.nocongrats)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.again,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        GoAct(3);
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNeutralButton(R.string.back_to_menu,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        GoAct(1);
                                    }
                                });
                return builder2.create();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

И мне кажется что именно в ней вся соль. Упущена какая то деталь.
Подскажите пожалуйста те кто сталкивался.

Comment: Попробуйте обернуть showDialog() в `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        showDialog(IDD_CONGRADS);
                    }
                });`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогает. Вообще ошибка возникает спонтанно, те изначально ее нет, и может не быть долго, а затем вот так внезапно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб может с моей стороны нужна какая то дополнительная информация, больше логов? Подскажите.

Comment: Единственное, что мне в голову приходит - попытка отображения диалога идёт поле onPause... Попробуйте флаг сделать в активити, коий будет true в onResume и false в onPause. И при запуске диалога проверять его. Если он false - не отображать диалог

Comment: @ЮрийСПб можете подсказать как это сделать, из того что сказали вы я не так много понял :(

Я попробую еще дополнительно описать ситуацию. В Handler происходит проверка равны ли массивы. При положительном исходе вызывается диалог `showDialog(IDD_CONGRADS)`, при отрицательном `showDialog(IDD_NOCONGRADS)` и именно на него указывает ошибка.  `showDialog(IDD_NOCONGRADS)` прописан там же где  `IDD_CONGRADS` как  `case`

Comment: Я тоже не понял что вы хотите сказать. Добавьте код в вопрос. А я имел в виду добавление в активити boolean переменной, коей надо присваивать значения в указанных методах и проверять это значение перед открытием дилога. Не факт, что это поможет

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил код. Понял насчет методов, попробую.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сейчас просмотрев еще раз код понял что влияю на Handler из метода onStart. И судя по тестам, это и есть причина. Спасибо за помощь. Можете добавить ответ если хотите, я отмечу как правильный.

Comment: Написал в ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, ошибка в том, что попытка отображения диалога происходит не между вызовами onResume и onPause. Убедитесь, что диалог не запускается после onPause или до onResume.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, `Handler` создаётся не в том потоке.
Попробуйте при создании запрашивать основной трэд.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Comment: Запрашиваю как вы сказали, тоже не помогает :(